# How can I update the values of an exposed view filter when another filter changes value?

Tags: views, 8, forms, ajax

I know there are several examples of this around, on a view with two exposed select list filters, I need to update the value of the second based on the value selected on the first. I can't even seem to get any debugging info on my callback, but the request is throwing a `Drupal\Core\Form\Exception\BrokenPostRequestException`. Here's the simple form alter I'm trying.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
    $form['field_article_value1_value']['#options']  = _MODULENAME_get_update_value1_values();
    $form['field_article_value2_value']['#options']  = _MODULENAME_get_value2_values();

    $form['field_article_value1_value']['#ajax'] = [
     'callback' => ['_MODULENAME_get_value2_values_ajax_callback'],
     'event' => 'change',
     'wrapper' => 'edit-field-article-value-wrapper',
     'progress' => [
     'type' => 'throbber',
     'message' => NULL,
     ],
  ];
}

function _MODULENAME_get_value2_values_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) : array {
  $markup = '<h1>Testing!</h1>';
  return ['#markup' => $markup];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This module might help: [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters)

If you really want a custom solution take a peek at the code there and see if it helps, or help the D8 version get released :)